# Directory import via index.js in Node.js

Tags: node.js, import

Im trying to import modules from directory and catching the error.

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import 'C:\js\tg_bot\constants' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from C:\js\tg_bot\index.js
Did you mean to import ../constants/index.js?
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tgbot",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@grammyjs/menu": "^1.0.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "grammy": "^1.7.0",
    "telegraf": "^4.7.0",
    "telegram-bot-api": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import {MSGS, KEYBOARD} from './constants'; 
console.log(MSGS)
```

constants/index.js

```
export { default as KEYBOARD } from './KEYBOARDS';
export { default as MSGS } from './MSGS';
```

constants/MSGS.js

```
export const MSGS = {
    START: 'My msg'
}
export default MSGS
```

command

```
node index.js
```

file structure:

```
/constants/index.js
/constants/KEYBOARD.js
/constants/MSGS.js
/index.js
...
```

I have some ideas about babel but havent ever used it.
In React project built with create-react-app everything works perfect.
Any help please)

Comment: Can I see your `/constants/index.js` exports?

Comment: Is there a package.json in the `constants` directory?  If so, please show that.  If there isn't a package.json in the constants directory, then you either need one or you need to import an explicit filename, not a directory.  Unlike CommonJS, ESM import doesn't imply certain filenames when you give it a directory.  It either uses the main entry point from a package.json file in that directory or you must specify the full filename that you are importing.  It doesn't automatically default to index.js like CommonJS does.

Comment: But you do can export from the `constants/index .js` like `export * from './KEYBOARD.js'` or `export {default} from './KEYBOARDS.js'`. That way when you try to access `'./constants'`  node will look at `constants/index.js` and find it

Answer (score 3):

This is from the Nodejs 18 doc

> Relative specifiers like './startup.js' or '../config.mjs'. They refer
> to a path relative to the location of the importing file. The file
> extension is always necessary for these.

I think this might be the solution for your problem:

```
import {MSGS, KEYBOARD} from './constants/index.js';
```